# ixudra/curl post multipart/form-data with different content type

Tags: laravel, rest, curl, multipartform-data

I am trying to post multipart/form-data in laravel using ixudra/curl that specify the data is application json. The problem Im facing right know is to assign the type for data and still make the header content type is multipart/form-data.

```
$contents = storage_path('app/curl.txt');
$dataJson = '{"bId":"79", "docId":"23"}';
$response = Curl::to($url)
->withHeaders( array( 
    'Authorization: Bearer 123432',
    'grant_type: jwt-bearer' ) )
->withData( array ('data' => $dataJson ))
->withFile('file', $contents, 'text/*', 'curl.txt')
->containsFile()
->withResponseHeaders()
->returnResponseObject()
->post();
```

For the curl, it is like this. Somehow, the error is "**Failure to Authenticate OAuth Token**" and the header content type is not multipart/form-data

```
curl -v -H "Authorization:Bearer 123432" 
-H "grant_type:jwt-bearer" 
-F "file=@\"/jet/app/www/default/test/storage/app/curl.txt\"" 
-F "data={\"bId\":\"79\", \"docId\":\"23\"};type=application/json" 
"https://url/private"
```

Any idea? thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

is this still an issue? Looking at your code, I don't see any errors in there. You don't need to include the `containsFile()` method in there but that's really a detail that won't effect your result in any way.

Based on your description, I doubt that the file has anything to do with the error. I'd recommend trying to make sure if the authentication is correct by using it on a simple GET request, just to make sure. If that works, you should dig deeper into the form.